# Solve for x in this (A.P) ifl

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic-progressions

Solve for x in this (A.P) if  $\log x + \log x^2 +\log x^3 .......+ \log x^n = n(n+1)$
So what I have found is a common difference, d is log x and a = log x but how do I solve for x??? the sum of this ap is n(n+1) i think

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) references.

Comment: Are the exponents for $x$ or for the logs?

Answer (score 2):

The sum of an $AP$ that increment by $1$ from $1$ to $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}2$.

Hence the problem reduces to $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\log x=n(n+1)$$

$$n(n+1)\log x=2n(n+1)$$

Hopefully you can simplify and solve for $x$ now.

Comment: Whatttt??? how did you get  n(n+1)/2 ??? and is it from the arithmetic means? and why times by log x

Comment: Each of those terms have a common factor of $\log x$ right? just factorize it out and focus on the sum from $1$ to $n$.